# How to get display name propert of contact

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios-simulator

I want display property of contact app.Like if i save contact with company name then it display with company.So how to find display name of contact with address book api.

like if i save a contact with company name and all other fields blank first name and last name then it shows company name for display the contact.If i save a contact with first name then it display with first name.I want the display value in contact app.

for eg

John

Dominios

I can easily get this first name and company name with address book api but how to find which property of contact is used for display the contact

Thanks in advance

Comment: Question doesn't make sense, do you mean you want to access all fields of each contact? Post the code you have now and tell us what it doesn't do.

Comment: why? it does make sense. he wants to get the display name without having to build it up

Answer (score 4):

get the composited name like this

```
ABRecordRef *person = (ABRecordRef *)[allPeople objectAtIndex:i];
NSString *displayName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);
```